# 1000 ip addresses

Tags: ip

I need to get 1000 ip addresses and run virtual server per each ip address, what are the best options of getting so many ip addresses?
Edit:
I am currently located in US.  One option is to buy VPS from web host, are the other options of hosting my own cheaper?

Comment: Do they need to be internet accessible?

Comment: I guess they don't need to run http server, but needs to be internet accessible

Comment: The two last comments are completely contradictory... Does 'unknown (google)' really know what it wants?

Answer (score 10):

That's a rather large block, that's better known as a /22.  That'll give you 1022 usable addresses.

How to get it very much depends on the rest of your situation.  Where in the world you are based, what your current network looks like.  You need to go to your transit provider and ask for their help, as they have to assign you these IPs from their address space.

Then you need routers and switches and all the rest of the network infrastructure to make it work.

At the moment, the question is a little vague.  Tell us more about your plans.

Answer (score 7):

Getting the addresses isn't a problem, you just have to justify them. If you want non-portable addresses, then you can simply apply to your upstream IP provider and they will allocate them to you, but if you want fully portable (ie you can move them to a completely new transit provider) you need to apply to your local issuer

If you're in the US, goto [ARIN](https://www.arin.net/), Asia [APNIC](http://apnic.net/) and others around the world for the EU and Middle East.

Answer (score 5):

100O IP addresses is nothing. This afternoon, I used the (free) services of  [Hurricane Electric](http://tunnelbroker.net/) and got 18446744073709551616 addresses in a few clicks (`2001:470:1f11:3aa::/64`, try it out, the `2001:470:1f11:3aa::bad:dcaf` should reply).

Of course, if you insist on using the old IPv4 protocol, your chances are limited. Its pool is [almost over](http://www.potaroo.net/tools/ipv4/index.html).

Comment: +1, I've just spent the last 20 mins playing with this - works a treat.

Answer (score 4):

Use a /22 subnet and addresses in the 10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255 range?

Answer (score 4):

If you need these IPs for (apache) SSL vhosts. Take a look at the [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) TLS extension, which allows one to run **more than one** SSL vhost with only **one** IP. But be warned that SNI is AFAIK not (yet) supported for WinXP Clients. :-(

Comment: That's a reasonable advice and I do not see why it has been downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split those ip addresses to many virtual servers for example for ssl hosting you should contact your datacenter provider and ask him for some /22. Of course that's not that easy, you will have to justify this assigment, and this should be pretty good explanation... Prepare for many questions and explanations.